# Desire2Learn CCQ API gives 403 with administrative service account

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I tried the rest call to /d2l/api/custom/1.1/ccq/request/ as documented (or as I interpreted the documentation), but I get a 403 when I try to submit a CCQ request.

I am running with a service account that has administrator rights.  However, when I look in the permissions tool it does not bring up any options for CCQ.  Have these calls been deprecated?  I noticed that they say they are only available in v1.1 of the API.  Is there a better way to do automated course content copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions about D2L's customizations might be answered here, but the best place to start with such a question is to contact D2L's customer support system directly.

That said, starting with LMS v10.4.0, a [simple set of course content copy APIs](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#id1) are available. You can use these to initiate content copy tasks, and control to some extent the items to copy, from one existing host org unit to another existing target org unit.

Comment: Thanks, I will contact support and if I can't get this figured out likely wait for the new API's.